# How to use WHERE statement in sqlite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have got the sqlite query to delete an entry in the database on a button click all working fine now, i didnt require the need to have a 2nd WHERE statement either in the end. I Will no doubt need to clean my code up a bit but i just wanted to make sure it was working first

```
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this account?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            connAccount.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())
            {

                // adds customers details to the database
                cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM account WHERE accid = '" + Global.selectedAccountID.ToString() + "';";
                MessageBox.Show("Account Deleted", "Account Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connAccount.Close();

            }

        }
        if(dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            
        }
        if (cb_active.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            active();
        }
        if (cb_active.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            inactive();
        }
        else
        {
            showAccounts();
        }
        cb_active.SelectedIndex = -1;
        connAccount.Close();

    }
```

Comment: The DGV doesn't automatically repaint.  So you have to read the database again.  The to make sure DGV is repainted set datasource to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I'm not an expert in C# but I guess that `ExecuteDeleteQuery()` is a custom method which actually performs the deletion. So you should post its code.

Comment: What type is  custid  and active in your db

Comment: The return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()` is the number of the deleted rows, so you can check it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: You should dispose your connection and command objects with `using`, do **not** cache connections

Comment: thats for the comments guys, managed to get it all working, ive updated my post to show what i ended up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the value of deleteQuery is correct as follows:

1. Copy the value of deleteQuery
2. Paste the value, a SQL script, into SSMS
3. Execute the SQL script in SSMS and check if it runs without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use bind variables! As long as you use literals - you will always have similar problems